# PHP takes a lot of time to insert data in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this code to insert a csv file in MySQL using PHP. It gets inserted fine but takes more than 30 secs to do so even though the file has only 20 records. I can see in MySQL that the records are uploaded but it will still show loading on the webpage. Please help me find the fault.

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("sg",$con);

define('CSV_PATH','C:/Users/mkutbudd/Desktop/');
$csv_file = CSV_PATH . $_POST['name'];

if (($getfile = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) { 
   $data = fgetcsv($getfile, 1000, ",");
   while (($data = fgetcsv($getfile, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
      $num = count($data); 
      for ($c=0; $c < 1; $c++) {
         $result = $data; 
         $str = implode(",", $result); 
         $slice = explode(",", $str);
         $col1 = $slice[0]; 
         $col2 = $slice[1];

         $query = "INSERT INTO dummy(DeclarationNo,dum3) VALUES('".$col1."','".$col2."')";
         $s=mysql_query($query, $con ); 
      }
   } 
}
echo "File data successfully imported to database!!";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location=\"fetch22.php\";</script>";
mysql_close($con); 
?>
```

Comment: What is the point of this loop `for ($c=0; $c < 1; $c++) {` ?

Comment: What's going on with that `for` loop?

Comment: There is even more redundant or unnecessary code in there. Why imploding and exploding right after each other? Why are you doing `fgetcsv` twice?

Comment: Also note that you have a critical security issue by not sanitizing `$_POST['name']`.

Answer (score 0):

check my below script,

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("sg",$con);

define('CSV_PATH','C:/Users/mkutbudd/Desktop/');
$csv_file = CSV_PATH . $_POST['name'];

if (($getfile = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) { 
   //$data = fgetcsv($getfile, 1000, ",");
   while (($data = fgetcsv($getfile, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
      $num = count($data); 
      $row=array();
      for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
         $row[]=$data[$c];
      }

      $query = "INSERT INTO dummy(DeclarationNo,dum3) VALUES('".$row[0]."','".$row[1]."')";
      $s=mysql_query($query, $con ); 
   } 
}
echo "File data successfully imported to database!!";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location=\"fetch22.php\";</script>";
mysql_close($con); 
?>
```

I can see your insertion goes in wrong place. Correct my code, if any typo errors exists.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't use the mysql library anymore. Go for mysqli or PDO.

And as answer to your question, there is a function `LOAD DATA INFILE` from mysql which reads directly a CSV file. More information about it in the [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).

example from the reference with discarded rows:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
  INTO TABLE t1
  (column1, @dummy, column2, @dummy, column3);
```